# HttpRuntime.Cache is not expiring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a problem with the following code. I have the following code,

```
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] == null)
            {
                AddTask(cacheKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), 60 * 30);
            }
            r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey].ToString());
            HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r); 


           private static void AddTask(string key, string value, int seconds)
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, null,
                    DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                    CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved));
            }

    public static void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
    {
    }
```

What I am doing is simply adding and updating(if exist) the cache. Then after 10 seconds I wanna to check something. But my CacheItemRemoved callback never called.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the item is going to be removed - that's not the point of a cache. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Adding and updating item in the cache. and after some interval i want to remove the cache and in the callback save all cache data.

Comment: Okay, `Cache` isn't going to work for that. For one, it doesn't guarantee you that the item is removed, ever - and for two, it doesn't guarantee you that when the item *is* removed, the callback is called and finishes executing. It's a cache, not a write buffer - if you need a write buffer, you need to make one of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever update the cache using

```
HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
```

then cache time reset to the default time. Now instead of using string now i used object instance without updating cache.its worked

```
notification = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as Notification;
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, notificationResult , null,
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved));
```